# Cannot connect remotely to WebSocket server with React App, running in Expo

Tags: react-native, websocket, server, expo, ws

I have been unsuccessful in trying to make a WebSocket connection between a React Native app client (running in Expo) and a NodeJs server, using the 'ws' websocket library on both sides.

I have set up the WebSocket server, which I can successfully connect to using a chrome extension websocket client, after entering the ip address and port e.g. 'ws://192.168.208.1:8080'.

I have set up the client code within the app but it cannot connect to the server! However I am able to connect to and send messages to the Websocket echo url 'wss://echo.websocket.org/' with no problem!

So the code is working correctly on both sides in the test cases, it seems like there is a problem making that remote connection.

**Sanity checks**
1. Both devices are on the same wi-fi network
2. I have tried connecting after disabling firewall

CLIENT CODE:

```
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
        // this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.208.1:8080/');

        // THIS DOES WORK!
        // this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/');

        this.ws.onopen = (evt) => console.log('connected');

        this.ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
            this.ws.send(JSON.stringify('Hello!'));
        });

        this.ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
            console.log('Received:', event.data);
        });
```

Comment: Is there any error logs or messages ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use https://ngrok.com  to expose your localhost server to public . then use the public url that this tool gives you inside your app.